# Gulp ignore folders with certain name

Tags: gulp

With gulp, is there a way to ignore certain folders within a directory?

For example, I have an images folder:

```
images
  |_ en_US/
  |_ en_GB/
  |_ de_DE/
  |_ someOtherFolder/
  |_ image1.jpg
  |_ image2.jpg
```

Can I target all the images except the ones inside any folder that matches [two letters]_[two letters]? So in this case, I would want to run a task that does something to any image except any image inside "en_GB", "en_US" or "de_DE"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter) plugin.